# How to display slope of a section of a line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

basically I have a dataset where I only want to find the slope of a section of the line that I plotted. Every answer I've seen has only explained how to create a general line of best fit, however that is not relevant to what I need.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook in python 3, with pandas, matplotlib.pyplot, numpy, and have imported linregress from scipy.stats (per the instructions of another post explaining how to calculate the slope).

Here is the figure I've plotted using two dataframes that I've defined as df and df2.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
line1 = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'],df['Oxygen (μmol/L)'], 'b-', label='1mM Ru(Eto)(bpy) with 20eq Ce')
line2 = plt.plot(df2['Time (s)'],df2['Oxygen (μmol/L)'], 'r-', label='1mM Ru(tpy)(bpyCO)PF_6 with 20eq Ce')
plt.legend()
```

[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlLZZ.jpg)

Basically I want to display the slope of the line of best fit where the lines aren't completely flat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some threshold to grab the subset of your arrays that isn't flat. Something along the lines of

```py
idx = np.array([])

for i in range(len(array)):
if np.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]) > some_threshold:
   idx = np.append(idx,i)

new_array = array[idx[0]:idx[-1]]
```

Then you can do a best fit line on `new_array`

(This is not the 'cleanest' way to do this by any means but it's a sketch to give the general idea)